# Is the Elementalist glyph triggered by "+X elemental damage" affixes?

Tags: diablo-iv

The Elementalist Glyph says:

> Dealing Fire, Cold, or Lightning damage to an enemy increases all damage you deal to them by 5%[x] for 10 seconds, stacking once per element.

I have an item with this affix:

> +20% Lightning Damage

Does this mean *all* my skills now do lightning damage, and this counts for the Elementalist trigger?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately not.

+20% Lightning Damage means that if you were to deal 80-100 damage which was a type of lightning (Chain Lightning for example), then you would benefit an additional 20% damage on top, so a perfect 100 would become 120.

+20% Lightning Damage will not help you if you are casting/using Cold, Physical, Poison, or Fire.